# How to return 0 instead of null when counting?

Tags: postgresql

I have a query:

```
with comments_info as (
        SELECT p.post_id as post_id,
               COUNT(p.id) as comments
        FROM post_comments p
        GROUP BY post_id
    )
select p.id as post_id, c.comments
from posts p
             left join comments_info c on c.post_id = p.id
```

But if there are no comments on the post, then count returns null.
I tried to do like this:

`CASE WHEN COUNT(p.id) IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE COUNT(p.id) END as comments`

but it still returns null.

Comments model:

```
 id pk,

 post_id fk,

 description text,
```

Posts model:

```
id pk,
title varchar,
description text,
```

Comment: Use coalesce(c.comments, 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `COALESCE` by wrapping your count, [see](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html)

```
COALESCE(count(p.id),0) as comments
```

**As per comment:**

use `COALESCE` in the outer query:

```
COALESCE (p.comments, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `COALESCE` in the outer query:

```sql
-- with clause omitted
select
  p.id as post_id,
  coalesce(c.comments, 0) as comments
-- from, join omitted
```

When there are no comments for a post, its count will not be null; there won't be a row, so the left join will return null for all columns of `comments_info`.

`coalesce()` returns the first non-null value of its parameters.